# Cannot make give my div, width 100%

Tags: html, css, width

[This is the site I am working on](http://fortrex.malcolmtanti.com/test/)

My Site is divided into 3 sections, Header, content and footer.

In the content div, I have different sub-div's. The last two div's, named contactsales and latestnews do not want to stretch my screens width, even though I specify the div to be width: 100%;

What could be the problem, I've checked my code over and over but cannot seem to spot my error

This is my CSS for the content div:

```
    #content{
    width: 100%;
}
#content #rowCopy{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#content #services{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#content #rowCopy #box {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 17px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.82);
    margin: 10px;
    padding:0;
    top: -50px;
}

#content #rowCopy #box #innercontent {
    width:75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-sm-3 {
    width: 22%;
    min-width: 230px;
}

.col-md-4{
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 230px;
}

#content #services #box {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 17px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.82);
    margin: 10px;
    padding:0;
}


#content #contactsales {
  background-color: rgb( 242, 242, 242 );
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 91px;
}

#content #contactsales #inner {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#content #latestnews{
    background: url("../images/blurimg.jpg"); 
    height: 574px;
    width: 100%;
}

#content #latestnews #title{
    color: rgba(200,200,200,0.7);
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: bold;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#content #latestnews #inner{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content #latestnews #inner #box{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 17px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.82);
    margin: 10px;
    padding:0;
}

#content #latestnews #inner #box #innercontent{
    padding: 15px;
}

#content #latestnews #inner #box #innercontent h4{
    font-weight: bold;
}

#content #latestnews #inner #box #news{
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: rgb(220,220,220);
}

#content #latestnews #inner #box #news h5{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The HTML is rather long for me to include it here

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's the child div with the id of `inner` that's got margin added to it on both the left and the right hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your div#content  to the code below.

```
<div id="content">
            <div id="slider">
                 <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0px auto; top: -7px; left: 0px; width: 1350px; height: 633.461538461539px; overflow: hidden;" jssor-slider="true">
                    <!-- Slides Container -->


                    <!--#region Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
                    <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-bullet-navigator-jquery.html -->

                    <!-- bullet navigator container -->

                    <!--#endregion Bullet Navigator Skin End -->

                    <!--#region Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
                    <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-arrow-navigator-jquery.html -->

                    <!-- Arrow Left -->

                    <!-- Arrow Right -->

                    <!--#endregion Arrow Navigator Skin End -->

                <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 610px; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: scale(1.03846153846154);"><div class="" style="position: relative; margin: 0px auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 610px; overflow: visible; display: block;"><div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 610px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;"><div debug-id="slide_container" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; pointer-events: none; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div></div><div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 610px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;" debug-id="slide-board"><div style="width: 1300px; height: 610px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; display: none; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
                                <div debug-id="slide-0" style="width: 1300px; height: 610px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;"><img u="image" src="./images/image.jpg" border="0" style="width: 1500px; height: 610px; top: 0px; left: -100px; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1300px; height: 610px; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1000; display: none;"></div></div>
                                <div debug-id="slide-1" style="width: 1300px; height: 610px; top: 0px; left: 1300px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;"><img u="image" src="./images/image.jpg" border="0" style="width: 1500px; height: 610px; top: 0px; left: -100px; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1300px; height: 610px; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1000; display: none;"></div></div>
                                <div debug-id="slide-2" style="width: 1300px; height: 610px; top: 0px; left: -1300px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;"><img u="image" src="./images/image.jpg" border="0" style="width: 1500px; height: 610px; top: 0px; left: -100px; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1300px; height: 610px; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1000; display: none;"></div></div>
                    </div><style>
                        /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 21 css */
                        /*
                        .jssorb21 div           (normal)
                        .jssorb21 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
                        .jssorb21 .av           (active)
                        .jssorb21 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
                        .jssorb21 .dn           (mousedown)
                        */
                        .jssorb21 {
                            position: absolute;
                        }
                        .jssorb21 div, .jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av {
                            position: absolute;
                            /* size of bullet elment */
                            width: 19px;
                            height: 19px;
                            text-align: center;
                            line-height: 19px;
                            color: white;
                            font-size: 12px;
                            background: url(./images/bullets.png) no-repeat;
                            overflow: hidden;
                            cursor: pointer;
                        }
                        .jssorb21 div { background-position: -5px -5px; }
                        .jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -5px; }
                        .jssorb21 .av { background-position: -65px -5px; }
                        .jssorb21 .dn, .jssorb21 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -5px; }
                    </style><div u="navigator" class="jssorb21" style="bottom: 26px; right: 6px; width: 73px; height: 19px; left: 613.5px;">
                        <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->

                    <div u="prototype" class="av" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div><div u="prototype" class="" style="position: absolute; left: 27px; top: 0px;"></div><div u="prototype" class="" style="position: absolute; left: 54px; top: 0px;"></div></div><style>
                        /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 21 css */
                        /*
                        .jssora21l                  (normal)
                        .jssora21r                  (normal)
                        .jssora21l:hover            (normal mouseover)
                        .jssora21r:hover            (normal mouseover)
                        .jssora21l.jssora21ldn      (mousedown)
                        .jssora21r.jssora21rdn      (mousedown)
                        */
                        .jssora21l, .jssora21r {
                            display: block;
                            position: absolute;
                            /* size of arrow element */
                            width: 55px;
                            height: 55px;
                            cursor: pointer;
                            background: url(./images/arrows.png) center center no-repeat;
                            overflow: hidden;
                        }
                        .jssora21l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
                        .jssora21r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
                        .jssora21l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
                        .jssora21r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
                        .jssora21l.jssora21ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; }
                        .jssora21r.jssora21rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }
                    </style><span u="arrowleft" class="jssora21l" style="top: 277.5px; left: 8px; display: none;">
                    </span><span u="arrowright" class="jssora21r" style="top: 277.5px; right: 8px; display: none;">
                    </span><a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Image Slider</a></div></div></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rowCopy">
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3" id="box">
                    <div id="innercontent">
                    <h3>WELCOME TO FORTREX</h3>
                    <p>
                        But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete count of the system, and expound the actual teaings of the great explorer idea announcing. But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain

                    </p><p>
                        <a href="#">MORE ABOUT US ❱</a>
                    </p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3" id="box"><img width="100%" src="./images/datamanagement.jpg">

                    <div id="innercontent">
                    <h3>DATA MANAGEMENT</h3>
                    <p>
                        But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete count of the system, and expound the actual teaings of the great explorer idea announcing. But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain

                    </p><p>
                    <a href="#">READ MORE ❱</a>
                    </p></div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3" id="box"><img width="100%" src="./images/storageservices.jpg">


                    <div id="innercontent">
                    <h3>STORAGE SERVICES</h3>
                    <p>
                        But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete count of the system, and expound the actual teaings of the great explorer idea announcing. But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain

                    </p><p>
                    <a href="#">READ MORE ❱</a>
                    </p></div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3" id="box"><img width="100%" src="./images/aviationstorage.jpg">


                    <div id="innercontent">
                    <h3>AVIATION STORAGE</h3>
                    <p>
                        But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete count of the system, and expound the actual teaings of the great explorer idea announcing. But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain

                    </p><p>
                    <a href="#">READ MORE ❱</a>
                    </p></div>

                </div>
            </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <div id="services">
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding: 0;"><h1>OUR SERVICES</h1></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8" style="padding: 0; padding-top: 20px;"><hr></div>
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" id="box">
                    <div id="inner">
                            <div class="col-md-4"><h5 style="font-weight: bold;">PACKAGING AND STORAGE</h5>
                            <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 10px;"><img src="./images/packaging.jpg"></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" id="box">
                    <div class="col-md-4"><h5 style="font-weight: bold;">TRANSPORT</h5>
                            <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 10px;"><img src="./images/trans.jpg"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" id="box">
                    <div class="col-md-4"><h5 style="font-weight: bold;">WORLDWIDE TRANSPORT</h5>
                            <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 10px;"><img src="./images/globtrans.jpg"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both">
                    <div class="col-md-4" id="box">
                    <div class="col-md-4"><h5 style="font-weight: bold;">WAREHOUSING</h5>
                            <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 10px;"><img src="./images/warehousing.jpg"></div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" id="box">
                        <div class="col-md-4"><h5 style="font-weight: bold;">DOOR-TO-DOOR DELIVERY</h5>
                            <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 10px;"><img src="./images/delivery.jpg"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" id="box"> 
                    <div class="col-md-4"><h5 style="font-weight: bold;">GROUND TRANSPORT</h5>
                            <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistakn idea of </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 10px;"><img src="./images/groundtrans.jpg"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div style="clear:both; padding:20px;"></div>


        </div>
  <div id="contactsales">
        <div id="inner">
            <div class="col-md-8" style="top: 35px; font-size: 20px;">Not Sure which Solution fits your buiness needs?</div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="top: 20px;"><a href="#"><img src="./images/contactsales.jpg"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="latestnews">
        <div id="inner">
            <div id="title">
                LATEST NEWS
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" id="box">
                <img width="100%" src="./images/example1.jpg">
                <div id="innercontent">
                    <h4>NEW PREMISES INAUGURATED BY JOSEPH MUSCAT PRIME MINISTER OF MALTA</h4>
                    <p>By Ryan it-Triplex</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" id="box">
                <img width="100%" src="./images/example2.jpg">
                <div id="innercontent">
                    <h4>THE FIRST AVIATION ‘FORTRESS’ in MALTA OPENS</h4>
                    <p>By Ryan it-Triplex</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" id="box">
                <div id="news">
                    <h5>NEW PREMISES INAUGURATED BY JOSEPH MUSCAT PRIME MINISTER OF MALTA</h5>
                    <p>By Ryan it-Triplex</p>
                </div>
                <div id="news" style="background: rgb(240,240,240)">
                    <h5>THE FIRST AVIATION ‘FORTRESS’ in MALTA OPENS</h5>
                    <p>By Ryan it-Triplex</p>
                </div>
                <div id="news">
                    <h5>THE FIRST AVIATION ‘FORTRESS’ in MALTA OPENS</h5>
                    <p>By Ryan it-Triplex</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>

</div>
```

What I did is that I move the #contactsales and #latestnews out of the #services and put next to the #services.

Answer (score 1):

This is because both are taking 100% width of what their `parent` allocated then.

Their immediate parent is `#services`, and it uses 80% of the webpage width as defined by its CSS.

Change this:

```
#content #services {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

to this:

```
#content #services {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Current structure:

[image]

You have a syntax error on line 306 of your code: 
`<div style="clear:both"/>`
change to to this: `<div style="clear:both"> </div>`

**div** tags should always have an explicit matching closing tag.

This will separate *#contactsales* and *#newslatest* from *#services*

Comment: Then I suspect I have a missing closing </div> tag. I want the services section (where there are the tiles) to be 80%, whereas the following section should be 100%.

Services shouldnt be a parent of contactsales and latestnews

Comment: @MalcolmTanti Probably. I just updated the answer with a picture of the structure as currently interpreted by the web-browser. You can see _#contactsales_ and _#latestnews_ being child of _#services_

Comment: Thanks, yes I see what you mean, indeed its a missing </div>

Answer (score 1):

This is because `contactsales` and `latestnews` divs are present inside `div` having `id="services` which has `width: 80%`.

So either remove the two divs outside the `<div id="services>`, or give `width: 100%` to `#services div` i.e.

```
#content #services {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

See the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because your last 2 divs is inside div with id = `services`. If you want last 2 divs is full width, you should move it out of `div#services`. You can move your div to footer div below it like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you are using percentage in height and width in CSS, it means that you want for example 80% of your reference width, which is the width of the parent. here you have *#service* as parent of *#contactsales* and *#latestnews*.

*#service* parent is *#content*. *#service* width is 80% of your *#content* and #contactsales and #latestnews are 100% of their parent.means 80% of #content too.

If you do not want to move #contactsales and #latestnews you should wrap them with someclass and change that class refrence width with *position:absolute*, and set *position:relative* to #content.Now these two Ides think of #content as their parent.
but I don't recommend position:absolute,just move them from #service

```css
.wrapperclass{
   position : absolute;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
}
#content{
   position: relative;
   width:100%;
   left:0;
}
#content #contactsales{
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  height:40px;
  position:relative
}
#content #latestnews{
  width:100%;
  background-color:green;
  position:relative;
  height:40px
}
#service{
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  height:120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<div id="service">
  <div class="wrapperclass">
    <div id="contactsales"></div>
    <div id="latestnews"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```